# Mongo - split 1 query into N queries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of millions  of docs as follows:

```
{
  customerId: "12345" // string of numbers
  foo: "xyz" 
}
```

I want to read every document in the collection and use the data in each for a large batch job. Each customer is independent, but 1 customer may have multiple docs which must be processed together.

I would like to split the work into N separate queries i.e. N tasks (that can be spread over M clients if N > M).

**How can each query consider different exclusive and adjoining sets of customers efficiently?**

One way might be for task 1 to query all customers who's ids start with "1"; task2 to query all docs for all customers who's ids start with "2" etc - giving N=10, which is spreadable over up to 10 clients. Not sure whether querying by substring is fast though. Is there a better method?

Comment: The collection can change between queries - that's ok - just as long as each individual customer's docs are only ever returned by 1 of the N queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `$skip` / `$limit` operators to split your data into separate queries.

### Pseudocode

```
I assume MongoDB driver automatically generates an ObjectId for the _id field

var N = 10;
var M = db.collection.count({});

// We calculate how many tasks we should execute
var tasks = M / N + (M % N > 0 ? 1 : 0);

//Iterate over tasks to get fixed amount data for each job
for (var i = 0; i < tasks; i++) {
    var batch = db.collection.aggregate([
        { $sort  : { _id : 1 } },
        { $skip  : i },
        { $limit : N },
        //Use $lookup "multiple docs"
    ]).toArray();

    //i=0 data:  0 - 10
    //i=1 data: 11 - 20
    //i=2 data: 21 - 30
    ...
    //i=100 data: 1000 - 1010
    //Note: If there are no enough N results, MongoDB will return 0 ... N records

    // Process batch here
}
```

### Traceability

How can you know if job finished or not? Where job stuck?

Add extra fields once you finish job execution:

```
jobId     - You can know what task processed this data
startDate - When did data processing started
endDate   - When did data processing finished
```

Comment: I don't want to use skip and limit as I can't be sure that the collection won't change between the queries (see my comment above). Taking your query as an example, if the full set of customerIds was [1, 5, 8, 13, 15] and the tasks should only return up to 3 results each, we expect the first task to get [1, 5, 8] and the second to get [13, 15] which is fine. But if between both tasks a new customerId "3" appeared in the collection, the two tasks would return [1, 5, 8] and [8, 13, 15] which is not fine. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @AnthonyLeonard If you don't override `_id` field (filled by MongoDB as ObjectId), sorting by `_id` will guarantee your new customers sorted correctly, because ObjectId contains timestamp

Comment: That would indeed work! If you could edit your answer as such I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you :)